# WebSQL check value is integer

Tags: sqlite, web-sql

I have a WebSQL Sqlite database on a Android device via PhoneGap. I want to run a query to delete all rows where the Id is not an integer. So I would like to run something like

```
DELETE FROM Client WHERE NOT IsInt(Id)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [typeof](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof):

```
DELETE FROM Client WHERE typeof(Id) <> 'integer'
```